# Sorting Pages by most views

Tags: xdb, best-practices, sitecore-client

I have a requirement in our 8.1 update 2 solution to provide a sorting mechanism for pages based on the number of views. This data lives in the analytics database and I'm looking for a way to retrieve the data without querying the database directly. Is there an API in place out of the box that I can use to get an item's view count?

I've verified that the data I need exists in the `[Sitecore_Analytics].[dbo].[Fact_PageViews]` table. From a best practices standpoint, what is the best way to retrieve this data and use it in our components?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Here is how you can do this:

**1. Create reporting query item**

Create somewhere an item of template `/sitecore/templates/System/Analytics/ReportQuery`

Example fields configuration:

Write down an item **ID** somewhere, we will need it later.

[image]

**2. Create item based reporting query class**

Example code:

**Note**: This `Constants.ReportingQueries.ItemVisits` is an item ID of your reporting query item, put this into constant or pull from configuration.

```c#
public class ExampleVisitsQuery : ItemBasedReportingQuery
{
    public ExampleVisitsQuery(ReportDataProviderBase reportProvider = null)
        : base(Constants.ReportingQueries.ItemVisits, reportProvider)
    {
    }

    public ID ItemId { get; set; }

    public long Visits { get; protected set; }

    public override void Execute()
    {
        var parameters = new Dictionary<string, object>
        {
            {"@ItemId", ItemId}
        };

        var dt = this.ExecuteQuery(parameters);

        if (dt != null && dt.Rows.Count > 0)
        {
            var result = dt.Rows[0]["Visits"];
            if (result != null && result != DBNull.Value)
                Visits = (long)dt.Rows[0]["Visits"];
        }
    }
}
```

**3. Get your data**

This is where we get the data.

```c#
var query = new ExampleVisitsQuery (this.ReportDataProvider)
{
    ItemId = id
};

query.Execute();

long itemViews = query.Visits;
```

**Note:**
`this.ReportDataProvider` is an instance of `ReportDataProviderBase` type.

In this can be null

As a output you get number of views.

**4. Sort your data**

Once you get Visits for all items you can easily sort them.

Assuming you have got a list of items ids as an input here is what you can do:

```c#
if (entryIds.Any())
{
    var views = new Dictionary<ID, long>();

    foreach (var id in entryIds)
    {
        var query = new ExampleVisitsQuery(this.ReportDataProvider)
        {
            ItemId = id
        };

        query.Execute();

        var itemViews = query.Visits;

        if (itemViews > 0)
            views.Add(id, itemViews);
    }

    var ids = views.OrderByDescending(x => x.Value).Take(maxCount).Select(x => x.Key).ToArray();
}
```

source: [WeBlog](https://github.com/WeTeam/WeBlog)

Comment: is there a way to read from another datasource? for example, i want to read from table interactions in the xdb_collection.Shard0 database.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure if that's the best solution, but yes, you can get the information you're looking for using `Fact_PageViews` table.

You can use query like that:

```sql
SELECT TOP 10 ItemId, count(*) as c FROM Fact_PageViews GROUP BY ItemId ORDER BY c DESC
```

or with some more options:

```c#
string query = string.Format("SELECT TOP {0} ItemId, count(*) as c FROM Fact_PageViews WHERE Date > DATEADD(DAY, -{1}, GETDATE()) GROUP BY ItemId ORDER BY c DESC", itemsCount, timespan);
```

Comment: I did rough out a similar query that can provide the results needed. Ideally though I'd like to avoid querying the db directly, even Sitecore recommends against it from what I've seen. Not sure if it's possible though, which is why I reached out here.

Comment: I haven't seen any better solution. I've used this approach once or twice before.