# Sitecore 8.2 using analytics data in code

Tags: xdb, sql-database, reporting

I have followed the answer [here](https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/1221/sorting-pages-by-most-views/1223)
But I get a null reference exception if I do not create an instance of the `ReportDataProvider`. And when I do create an instance I am getting an error in the `ReportDataProvider` in the `GetData` function that says:

> Failed to get a datasource (item)".

`Item` is what the `QueryDataSource` is defaulted to, am I supposed to override this?

I am near the point of just doing this with direct SQL and an ADO connector but I really want to avoid this.  Our configuration is normal and nothing is out of the ordinary.

Comment: How do you instantiate ReportDataProvider? Is it something along these lines? (ReportDataProviderBase)Factory.CreateObject("reporting/dataProvider", true);

Comment: I have tried that I have also done it the traditional way with just creating a new object.  Once it is created it still just throws an error in GetData.

Comment: Also, doing that way I get an error: 'reporting/data‌​Provider' has an invalid token.  We are using the default configuration.  Nothing has been changed.