# Retrieving data from interactions table

Tags: xdb

Is there a way to retrieve data from table `xdb_collection.Interactions` in `xdb_collection.shard0` datasource in my code?

I already tried to use the method in the following link [Sorting Pages by most views](https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/1221/sorting-pages-by-most-views/1232#1232) but it only works with the reporting datasource.

Edit:
When trying the extraction approach i get the below error and the code exists.[image: extraction approach error]

Comment: Maybe this can help you  https://doc.sitecore.net/developers/xp/xconnect/xconnect-client-api/interactions/get-interactions/index.html

https://doc.sitecore.net/developers/xp/xconnect/xconnect-client-api/contacts/get-contacts/get-contact-interactions.html

Answer (score 3):

You **should not** query xdb_collection database. XConnect API is meant to be used for this type of scenarios. You have 2 ways to retrieve interactions from XDB database:

1. [Interaction extraction](https://doc.sitecore.net/developers/xp/xconnect/xconnect-client-api/data-extraction/extract-contact-and-interactions.html#extracting-interactions) to get all interactions only limited by date.
2. [Search interactions](https://doc.sitecore.net/developers/xp/xconnect/xconnect-client-api/search/interactions/index.html#search-by-interaction-property) if you need to have more complex search criteria.

---

Code samples taken from documentation for reference

### Extraction approach

```
using Sitecore.XConnect;
using Sitecore.XConnect.Collection.Model;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace Documentation
{
    public class DataExtraction
    {
        // Async interaction
        public async void ExampleAsync()
        {
            using (Sitecore.XConnect.Client.XConnectClient client = Sitecore.XConnect.Client.Configuration.SitecoreXConnectClientConfiguration.GetClient())
            {
                try
                {
                    // Extract interactions
                    var allInteractions = new List<Interaction>();
                    var interactionEnumerator = await client.CreateInteractionEnumerator(DateTime.UtcNow, new InteractionExpandOptions(), 200);
                    while (await interactionEnumerator.MoveNext())
                    {
                        foreach (var interaction in interactionEnumerator.Current)
                        {
                            allInteractions.Add(interaction);
                        }
                    }

                }
                catch (XdbExecutionException ex)
                {
                    // Manage exceptions
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

### Search based approach

```
using Sitecore.XConnect.Collection.Model;
using Sitecore.XConnect.Operations;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Linq;
using Sitecore.XConnect.Search;
using Sitecore.XConnect;
using Sitecore.XConnect.Client;

namespace Documentation
{
    public class SearchInteractionProperty
    {
        // Async example
        public async void ExampleAsync()
        {
            using (Sitecore.XConnect.Client.XConnectClient client = Sitecore.XConnect.Client.Configuration.SitecoreXConnectClientConfiguration.GetClient())
            {
                try
                {
                    var someChannelId = Guid.Parse("0565e9b0-936c-4594-8cc3-5fcace3918ed");

                    IAsyncQueryable<Sitecore.XConnect.Interaction> queryable = client.Interactions
                        .Where(x => x.ChannelId == someChannelId && x.StartDateTime > DateTime.UtcNow.AddDays(-10));

                    var enumerable = await queryable.GetBatchEnumerator(10);

                    while (await enumerable.MoveNext())
                    {
                        IReadOnlyCollection<Interaction> currentBatch = enumerable.Current;
                    }
                }
                catch (XdbExecutionException ex)
                {
                    // Handle exception
                }
            }
        }    
    }
}
```

Comment: i tried this method but i get the following error: '((Sitecore.XConnect.AsyncEntity Batch Enumerator<Sitecore.XConnect.Interaction>)interaction Cursor).Current' threw an exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' , any idea what i'm missing?

Comment: @AmiraElEwady, could you please update the question with your code sample that's failing?

Comment: @AmiraElEwady, I update the "Extraction approach" sample. You can give another try.

Comment: @grg I am trying the same code but var interactionEnumerator = await client.CreateInteractionEnumerator(DateTime.UtcNow, new InteractionExpandOptions(), 200); this line sometime kills the process... means whenever I am debugging it it is killing the debugger on same like