# Downloads table is empty in reporting DB

Tags: xdb, experience-analytics

I'm using Sitecore 9.1.1.
I have a requirement to track the downloads of PDF files across the site. I've marked the required files under the media library with the "Download" event and I am able to see them in the Experience Analytics dashboard under the behavior tab.

I need then to extract the download count of each item, I didn't find an OOTB API that allows me to do so but I found [this link](https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/1221/sorting-pages-by-most-views) which gives a way to extract information from the reporting DB.

But my problem is that the "Fact_Downloads" table in the reporting DB is always empty!

[image]

Any idea why the [Fact_Downloads] table is always empty? and where is the downloads data that's showing up in the analytics dashboard under the behavior tab is coming from in that case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used the following query with Sitecore 10, give it a try with your version:

```
SELECT        
    DimensionKeys.DimensionKey, 
    SiteNames.SiteName, 
    Fact_DownloadEventMetrics.Count, 
    Fact_DownloadEventMetrics.Visits, 
    Fact_DownloadEventMetrics.Value

FROM
    DimensionKeys INNER JOIN
    Fact_DownloadEventMetrics ON DimensionKeys.DimensionKeyId = Fact_DownloadEventMetrics.DimensionKeyId INNER JOIN
    SiteNames ON Fact_DownloadEventMetrics.SiteNameId = SiteNames.SiteNameId

GROUP BY 
    DimensionKeys.DimensionKey, 
    SiteNames.SiteName, 
    Fact_DownloadEventMetrics.Count, 
    Fact_DownloadEventMetrics.Visits, 
    Fact_DownloadEventMetrics.Value
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your solution, I gave it a try and it returned the results. One more question please, any idea what is the difference between "Count" and "Visits" for downloads here? they are always the same for all the returned items.

Comment: Visits, Is Number of interactions where there was one or more downloads. Count, Number of times the item was downloaded:
https://doc.sitecore.com/en/users/81/sitecore-experience-platform/the-dimensions-and-metrics-in-experience-analytics-reports.html