# How can I get all sitecore download event tracking list of item which is not clicked yet (like zero visit items)

Tags: xdb, powershell-extensions, experience-analytics, powershell

I am using **Sitecore 10.2** having `Sitecore Analytics` enabled.

Download events tracking analytics is enabled for all media items like(**.pdf, .docs, .xls**).

How to get all media items which have not been clicked yet or having zero visits count?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Associating Files With The Download Goal
From the Sitecore launchpad, click Media Library.

[image]

Click on the Media Library icon on the Sitecore launchpad.

In the content tree, select the PDF item you’d like to track downloads of.

[image]
Select a file in the Sitecore media library content tree.

In the top navigation bar, select Analyze, and then Attributes.

[image]

Select Analyze, then Attributes from the Sitecore top navigation.

Click Events, and select Download.
[image]
Select Events, then Download after clicking Attributes in the top navigation.

Click OK, then remember to Save and Publish.
[image]
Click the OK button.

Reviewing Results
To review the results, from the Sitecore launchpad, click Experience Analytics.

Click Experience Analytics from the Sitecore launchpad.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you open the Database, there are some tables that maintain the tracking under `Reporting database`. So you can run the query like the one below.

```
SELECT DimensionKeys.DimensionKey, 
   SiteNames.SiteName, 
   Fact_DownloadEventMetrics.Count, 
   Fact_DownloadEventMetrics.Visits, 
   Fact_DownloadEventMetrics.Value  
FROM
    DimensionKeys INNER JOIN
    Fact_DownloadEventMetrics ON DimensionKeys.DimensionKeyId = Fact_DownloadEventMetrics.DimensionKeyId INNER JOIN
    SiteNames ON Fact_DownloadEventMetrics.SiteNameId = SiteNames.SiteNameId
```

So You can check the details by adding where conditions into this.

Ref: [Downloads table is empty in reporting DB](https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/29400/downloads-table-is-empty-in-reporting-db)

Also under the reporting database there are some views already created that Enable you to query the `Fact_Downloads` table. So I found one that can help you to filter by `AssetId`.

```
SELECT * FROM [dbo].[Downloads]
```

You can find them under Views.

[image]

You can use this by adding the WHERE condition to filter the records.

If you want to run this using Powershell then you can write the query something like this.

```
Import-Function -Name Invoke-SqlCommand

$connection = [Sitecore.Configuration.Settings]::GetConnectionString("reporting")

$query = @"
SELECT TOP (10) *
  FROM [dbo].[table]
"@
Invoke-SqlCommand -Connection $connection -Query $query
```

Ref: https://doc.sitecore.com/xp/en/developers/81/sitecore-experience-platform/the-reporting-database-reference.html

Hope this helps.

Comment: how can we get a list of items from "Reporting database" that visit item is zero
with help of PowerShell script